# asp.net website to mobile/tablet

Tags: asp.net, css, mobile, tablet

I have an asp.net website, it contains database calls etc

Whats the best way of taking an existing asp.net website and making it look good in mobile and tablet devices?

I have done some research but there seems to be so many options eg lessframework.com, jquerymobile etc

I havent used mvc before but a few people say to use mvc + jquerymobile

any help would be muchly appreciated

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic bullet that will instantly convert your website to mobile. In fact without knowing the specifics of your website it would be hard to recommend a good fit for your situation since the tools you mention like MVC, JQMobile, etc. would be used in one case or another. With the question as you have posed it you will get personal opinion and there are millions of us with opinions... here's mine:

I would recommend not building a mobile specific website like mobile.website.com but rather look into responsive design where your website and the underlying data structs remain the same but your view changes depending on screen real-estate. Bootstrap or HTML5 Boilerplate or any number of design frameworks will help you get started. You just need to figure out a design that fits your websites functionality.

I use [MVC + HTML5 Boilerplate](http://nuget.org/packages/Html5Boilerplate.Mvc3.Razor) (I love Razor) for most of my new projects but sometimes even it has too much overhead so I just start from scratch (multiple PSD's, convert to HTML in Dreamweaver, apply logic with MVC & client side scripting) but that is something you will have to decide on a project by project basis.